# How to choose best parameters with a differential evolution algorithm

Tags: evolutionary-algorithm, particle-swarm, differential-evolution

for an assignment in class i need to optimize 4 10-dimensional functions, when implementing the differential evolution i noted that all the functions needed different parameter settings. By playing around it seemed that especially when choosing your crossover-rate high and your F around 0.5 seemed to work fine.

However on one function, the 10-dimensional Katsuura function, my differential algorithm seems to fail. I tried a bunch of parameters but keep scoring a 0.01 out of 10. Does differential evolution not work for certain objective functions?

I tried implementing PSO for this problem as well but that failed too so i seem to think this function has certain properties which can only be solved by certain algorithms?

i Inspired my DE on this article:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differential_evolution

With kind regards,

Kees Til

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the function you will notice that this function is pretty tough. It is something usual heuristics like DE and PSO to have problems with so tough functions. [image: Katsuura Function]